# Derivation of Gaussian Posterior

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, machine-learning, bayesian

This question is influenced by this: [Help in understanding Derivation of Posterior in Gaussian Process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890853/help-in-understanding-derivation-of-posterior-in-gaussian-process) .

The question is

1) What would happen if our posterior had this form: $p(w|X,y)= \frac{1}{D}p(y|X,w)p(w)$. Notice that $\frac{1}{D}$ is some constant, how do we deal with such a thing?

2) I noticed that in gaussian process book, they use a prior with $\mu=$ $0$. What if it was something like this: $p(w)=\mathcal{N}(w_{0},\Sigma)$. ?

Comment: 1) $\propto$ in the link you provided already means there are some constants on the RHS. Your $1/D$, wherever it comes from, will joint this company. 2) Replace $-\frac{1}{2} w^T \Sigma_p^{-1} w$ with $-\frac{1}{2} (w-w_0)^T \Sigma^{-1} (w-w_0)$ in the exponential.

Comment: @neek regarding 2) could you provide some more steps perhaps? I don't feel very comfortable with this kind of linear algebra!

Comment: $\displaystyle D=\int_w p(y|X,w)\,p(w)\, dw$ simply turns the likelihood times the prior density into a posterior *probability* density with $\displaystyle \int_w p(w|X,y)\, dw =1$

Comment: @Henry the confusion just grown exponentially now!

Comment: [D is a normalising constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizing_constant)

Comment: @Mpd. Jhn 2) will become trivial to you as soon as you learn about the multivariate normal distribution.